# Elementary extensions of $M^{\text{Sh}}$

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete first-order theory and $U$ a monster model. For a small subset $B\subset U$, define a language $L_B$ that contains a predicate $R_{\varphi(ub)}(u)$ for every formula $\varphi(ub)$ with parameters $b\in B$. Now any subset $A\subseteq U$ can be made into an $L_B$-structure $A_{\text{ind}(B)}$ in a natural way; take $A_{\text{ind}(B)}\models R_{\varphi(ub)}(a)$ to hold if and only if $U\models \varphi(ab)$. Given a small model $M\prec U$, and a small $|M|^+$-saturated elementary extension $M\prec O\prec U$, we refer to the structure $M_{\text{ind}(O)}$ as $M^{\text{Sh}}$, the "Shelah expansion" of $M$. The following is exercise 3.10 in Pierre Simon's [book](https://www.normalesup.org/%7Esimon/NIP_guide.pdf) on NIP theories:

> Let $M\prec U$ and let $\widehat{N}$ be an elementary extension of $M^{\text {Sh}}$ with $L$-reduct $N\prec U$. Show that, up to a renaming of the language, $\widehat{N}$ is equal to $N_{\text{ind}(B)}$ for some set $B\subset U$ of parameters.

I'm having a bit of trouble with this exercise. If I'm not mistaken, showing that $\widehat{N}$ is equal to $N_{\text{ind}(B)}$ means showing that the same sets of tuples from $N$ are definable in these structures. I'm able to find a subset $B\subset U$ such that every set definable in $\widehat{N}$ is definable in $N_{\text{ind}(B)}$ without much trouble, but I'm struggling to construct $B$ in such a way that $N_{\text{ind}(B)}$ doesn't have any *new* definable sets. Here is my approach.

Let $\varphi(uo)$ be any $O$-formula. Let $K=R_{\varphi(uo)}(\widehat{N})$, and consider the partial type in $w$ containing $\{\varphi(nw):n\in K\}$ and $\{\neg\varphi(nw):n\in N\setminus K\}$. Since $R_{\varphi(uo)}(M^{\text{Sh}})=\varphi(M;o)$, and since $M\prec U$, we know that, for any $k\in\omega$,
\begin{align}
M^{\text{Sh}}\models\forall u_1\dots u_k\forall v_1\dots v_k &\bigwedge_{i\in[k]}R_{\varphi(uo)}(u_i)\wedge\neg R_{\varphi(uo)}(v_i)\\
\to\exists w&\bigwedge_{i\in[k]}\varphi(u_iw)\wedge\neg\varphi(v_iw).
\end{align} Since $\widehat{N}\succcurlyeq M^{\text{Sh}}$, this carries up to $\widehat{N}$, and hence for any finite subsets $K_0\subseteq K$ and $K_1\subseteq N\setminus K$ we may find $e\in N$ such that $K_0\subseteq\varphi(Ne)$ and $K_1\subseteq\neg\varphi(Ne)$. So the partial type above is consistent, and hence there exists some $b_{\varphi(uo)}\in U$ such that $R_{\varphi(uo)}(\widehat{N})=\varphi(N;b_{\varphi(uo)})$.

Now if we take $B=\{b_{\varphi(uo)}:\varphi(uo)\in \text {Form}(O)\}$, then indeed every set definable in $\widehat{N}$ will be definable in $N_{\text{ind}(B)}$. But I don't think there any reason for the converse to hold in general; for example, this remark follows the exercise:

> Observe that in general $\widehat{N}$ is a proper reduct of $N^{\text{Sh}}$.

I think I see why this is the case. For example, suppose $T$ is the theory of the random graph. Then for any model $N\prec U$, we know that every subset of $N$ is definable in $N^{\text{Sh}}$; in particular, $N^{\text{Sh}}$ has $2^{|N|}$ definable subsets. But the number of definable subsets of $\widehat{N}$ is bounded by $\operatorname{max}\{|N|,|L_O|\}$, and hence if $N$ is sufficiently large (eg if $2^{|N|}>|O|$), then there will be no way for $\widehat{N}$ to have all of the definable subsets that $N^{\text{Sh}}$ does, just for cardinality reasons. Is this right?

So we need to find a way of avoiding this kind of behavior, ie to do something further to ensure that $B$ cannot add new definable sets to $\widehat{N}$; I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to approach this. The fundamental issue I'm grappling with is that, if we have a partial type in new variables $w_{\varphi(uo)}$, the realizations of which we want to take as the set $B$, it's unclear to me how we might express that $\bar{w}$-definable sets are $L_O$-definable in a first-order way. Any insight, or a hint, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try your approach, but for all formulas at once? That is, for every tuple $o$ from $O$, realize the partial type $p_o(w)$ saying that for all formulas $\varphi(x,o)$, an element is in the set defined by $\varphi(x,w)$ if and only if it satisfies $R_{\varphi(x,o)}$?

Ok, this doesn't quite work, because you need the tuples realizing these partial types to cohere appropriately. That is, if some tuples $o$ and $o'$ have some elements in common, you also want the tuples realizing $p_o(w)$ and $p_{o'}(w')$ to have the corresponding elements in common. Otherwise you could mix-and-match across tuples and possible get new definable sets.

So don't just handle all formulas at once, handle all formulas *and* all tuples at once. That is, generalize the above partial type to one in infinitely many variables, one for each element of $O$.

There are some details to check - this is more of a hint than a complete answer - but I think this idea works.